# find key with highest value in HashMap<String,Double> using lambdaj (java)

Tags: java, lambdaj

I try to find the find key having the hightest value in a HashMap < String,Double > using [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/). 
I guess selectMax() will help, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've downloaded lambdaj and gave it a try. Here you go

```
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.having;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.max;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.on;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.select;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class LambdaJtester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HashMap < String,Double >  mapp = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        mapp.put("s3.5", 3.5);
        mapp.put("s1.5", 1.5);
        mapp.put("s0.5", 0.5);
        mapp.put("s0.6", 0.6);
        mapp.put("2s3.5", 3.5);
        mapp.put("s2.6", 2.6);
        System.out.println(
                select(mapp.entrySet(), having(on(Map.Entry.class).getValue(), 
                        equalTo(max(mapp, on(Double.class)))))
        );
    }
}
```

prints out `[2s3.5=3.5, s3.5=3.5]`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this?

```
java.util.HashMap <String,Double> map;
java.util.Map.Entry<String,Double> entry;
double maxx = selectMax(map, on(entry.getClass()).getValue())
```

Comment: I got this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method on(Class<entry>) from the type Lambda refers to the missing type entry
 entry cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I'd also try `double maxx = max(map, on(entry.getClass()).getValue())` or `double maxx = maxFrom(map).getValue()`

Comment: As stated in the question aboe, I try to get the String with the highest Double in the HashMap. How do I do that?

Comment: You're right. By the way, did you manage to get the max value? Because that'd be a good start to retrieve not just the value but the whole Map.Entry. I'm busy now but later this day I plan to download and try this lambdaj.

Comment: I did use the following which seemed to work `double maxx = selectMax(map, on((Double.class)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @return the key of the highest value of this map. Note: if this map has
 *         multiple values that are the highest, it returns one of its
 *         corresponding keys.
 */
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> K keyOfHighestValue(Map<K, V> map) {
    K bestKey = null;
    V bestValue = null;
    for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (bestValue == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(bestValue) > 0) {
            bestKey = entry.getKey();
            bestValue = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return bestKey;
}
```

And one test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MapUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testKeyOfHighestValue() {

        Map<String, Double> mapp = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        mapp.put("s3.5", 3.5);
        mapp.put("s1.5", 1.5);
        mapp.put("s0.5", 0.5);
        mapp.put("s0.6", 0.6);
        mapp.put("2s3.5", 123.5); 
        mapp.put("s2.6", 2.6);

        assertEquals("2s3.5", MapUtils.keyOfHighestValue(mapp));
    }
}
```